# NodeJS server not receiving laravel events sent with redis

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis

I got a laravel application running with `php artisan serve` on port 8000 and I listen to the queue with `php artisan queue:listen` to listen to the events broadcasted by the application. I also got a redis server running on port 6379 but when I broadcast a message with `event(new TestEvent())`, the NodeJS server does not see the message. I tried 2 different node variants, variant 1 does not log a single message but variant 2 doesn't event start. Error message:

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis redis:6379
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
```

Laravel .env:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

TestEvent:

```
class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    private $message = 'hello';

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['home'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Node server variant 1:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const http = require('http');
const server = http.Server(app);

const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const io = socketIO(server);

const redis = require('redis');

const port = 3000;

io.on('connection' , (socket) => {
   console.log('user connected');

    socket.on('test1', (message) => {
        console.log(message);
    });
});

const redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.subscribe('test');
redisClient.subscribe('*');

redisClient.on('*', function(channel, message) {
   console.log(channel);
   console.log(message);
});

redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log(channel);
    console.log(message);

    // socket.emit(channel, message);
});

redisClient.on('test', function(channel, message) {
    console.log(channel);
    console.log(message);

    // socket.emit(channel, message);
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('started on port: ' + port);
});
```

Node variant 2:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis(6379, 'redis');

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server is running!');
});

function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //
});

redis.psubscribe('*', function(err, count) {
    //
});

redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "ioredis": "^2.4.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just to check, you should listen to what your broadcastAs function returns.

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=test
```

Otherwise, only the "default" broadcast event will be executed and the event will never fire.

If you want to listen the "default" as well:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=test,
```